# Small soft bursts of static and volume drops, is my audio hardware faulty?

Tags: windows, audio

I'm running Windows 7 using onboard audio. It's been fine for over 2 years but lately there's a problem every time I play audio. I only use WMP since it's the only player I've ever used with this pc.

I hear a small soft burst of static and the volume turns itself down from 50% to 23%. Once at 23%, it plays fine. 
No related events logged in viewer. 
No reported problems with the device. 
Different headphones, same problem. 
I played around with audio settings for hours but the problem persists.

**More information:**

Motherboard:

```
ECS G31T-M LGA775
```

System info displays this:

```
Name    High Definition Audio Device
Manufacturer    Microsoft
Status  OK
PNP Device ID   HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1106&DEV_E721&SUBSYS_10192683&REV_1001\4&3D4E739&0&0001
Driver  c: \Windows\system32\drivers\hdaudio.sys (6) 1. 7600. 16385, 297. 00 KB (304, 128 bytes), 14/07/2009 9: 51 AM)
```

I'll keep adding info as I find it.

The question I want resolved is: **Is it faulty hardware?** If so, I can buy a sound card. I can't imagine software is responsible since I haven't installed anything new for weeks. Virus scans are clear as well. The static burst is irritating to say the least. Tried 2 different headphones and separate speakers. Same problem.

Comment: What "Playing" software are you getting the problem with? The burst of noise is pure 100% static and not extreme distortion? (as it cleans up does it clean up instantally or as a "distortion" goes away)

Comment: Hi Psycogeek. I've been testing with WMP since it's the only player I've ever used with this pc. And it's definately static. The moment it dies off the volume is softer. Drives me nuts.

Comment: go to the manufacture http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=812&CategoryID=1&MenuID=16&LanID=0 And install the audio driver from there, not from some thing that is in windows updates. Corrupt files can have garbage in them,  Try MPC or VLC to verify the files. If it is the sound going through to a HDMI output (tv or hdmi connected monitor) then that is different.  It is way more likly to be some software , codec , filter, effect, or even a PCI latency issue, and not likly to be an unfixable hardware issue. Use the green jack, and mute REC items.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks for your help. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

When diagnosing any issue, always start with the easiest check. For likely hardware issues this means isolating software as a possible cause.

To do this you get a Live Linux disk of some sort (Ubuntu is easy to use and has very good hardware support) and run it on the computer and then try to replicate the issues.

If you get similar issues even using an entirely different set of software on the computer, then the issue is most likely hardware.

If you do NOT get any issues while using the different operating system, then the issue is most likely the operating system installed on the computer.

So, if the issue is software, then go through the normal steps of updating drivers, repairing your OS, and if necessary, reinstalling the operating system entirely.

If the issue is hardware, then just hope it is confined to the discrete hardware at issue (in this case, the sound card). Particularly with sound cards there are now USB sound devices which should allow you to "install" a new sound card without even opening the computer, if your needs are basic.

There is always the chance that the faulty hardware was just the first part that exhibited signs of failure, and that other parts are failing as well. So I wouldn't spend much money on any hardware fix, especially if it is the onboard audio for a desktop or laptop computer. I simply wouldn't trust the rest of the computer enough to spend more than a few dollars getting it running again. So things like USB audio devices make a lot of sense because they can also be used on other systems if indeed the rest of the system fails soon after.